# Unmanaged C++ Classes in C#

Tags: c#, c++, c++-cli, wrapper, unmanaged

I'm writing a program which utilizes a third party C++ library. I've written a C++/CLI wrapper to be able to expose some of the methods needed to my C# application, however I'm running into a bit of a problem.

The external library has a multitude of custom classes and objects that I'll need to have access to in order to do what I need to do. However, I won't be able to access these objects from within the C# application, where we would like to keep most of the business logic.

My question is: do I need to write C# versions of these objects to be able to pass them back through the C++/CLI wrapper, or is there an easier way to do this?

I'm using the B-TK framework (https://code.google.com/p/b-tk/) if that helps.

Comment: Clarification:  are you suggesting that P/Invoke cannot be the way?

Comment: Would that work if the returns are a custom objects that are defined in the library? I'm new to this whole Unmanaged C++ to Managed code thing, and I thought the wrapper would be the best solution. I could be very wrong however. Edit: Also, the returns in the unmanaged code are all "smart pointers" to the object.

Comment: They did the Python binding with SWIG.  That can also generate C++/CLI wrappers, worth a shot.

Comment: Yes Hans is right, when you have a lot of native classes using SWIG becomes an interesting solution. Writing C++/CLI wrappers by hand is good only when you have a small set of types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just as hard, but you're supposed to do the reverse: Write C++/CLI managed versions of these classes, that can be used from C#. Like the others said, if you can do it with a tool, you should.